# How to finish PayPal Activity from previous activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, paypal

I know there is many similar questions about this topic, but I couldn't figure out a solution from them, so sorry if it may sound duplicated.

In my app i'm using PayPal SDK v2.6. I have this order review activity, where I show to the user all the details of his order, and I have a pay button, which opens the PayPal payment activity.

 I want to prevent the user from holding too long in PayPal Activity, so, I started a 10 minutes timer, from the moment user clicks the button that opens PayPal Activity. 
**What i'm trying is to do is to finish PayPal activity from the code file of the order activity when the timer ends**, since the whole the PayPal procedure code is written in my order activity. 
I use PayPal with start activity for result and on result mechanism, I don't have any control of what's happening in PayPal, I'm just handling results.
Here is my code snippet for starting the PayPal service:

```
paypalServiceIntent = new Intent(this, PayPalService.class);
paypalServiceIntent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
startService(paypalServiceIntent);
```

Then I start the paypal activity like this:

```
startTimer(); // my timer mechanism
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("" + finalPrice), "HKD", subProduct.getString("SubProductName").trim(),
                                        PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
Intent intent = new Intent(ReviewOrderActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Then I have my timer code in the order class file (I added all the actions I tried to close paypal activity):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       stopService(paypalServiceIntent); // not closing paypal activity
       finish(); // not closing paypal
       onBackPressed(); // not closing paypal
       onDestroy(); // not closing paypal
       finishActivity(0); // not closing paypal
     }
}, 10*60*1000);
```

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: timer code placed in ReviewOrderActivity? PaymentActivity is your activity or from PayPal sdk?

Comment: Yep, whole code is in ReviewOrderActivity class file.

Comment: and PayPalActivity from the SDK?

Comment: Yeah it's from the SDK.

Comment: ok, your code closing ReviewOrderActivity that "live" behind paypal activity. your problem that you don't have any control on PayPalActivity, so i suggest to create new activity class and extends PayPalActivity, then you can override onNewIntent method and catch a new intent, in this new intent you send an extra param to close this activity (in the manifest file define the new activity class as single instance)

Comment: The concept I had in my mind is closing activity that was called with startActivityForResult. I tried to find something about it but no success yet.

Comment: Liran, I tried to extend the PayPal Activity, but it's not allowed:
"Cannot inherit from final 'com.paypal.android.sdk.payments.PaymentActivity'"

Comment: you can to do something else, you can to start another activity instead of try to finish those 2 activities :), in the "C" activity catch the onBackPressed for avoiding to navigate again to PayPalActivity

Comment: :) It's a workaround, but it works Liran. Still paypal exists in the memory it would be better to kill it. And another thing, i would prefer to go to C to the same state it was before i got to review page, now i have to figure out this.
Anyways thanks for the help bro.

Comment: I'm playing around with this, i've managed to some manipulations, but still it's important to kill PayPal Activity.

Comment: i think you can get the list of the activities in the stack and get the current instance and finish him